# Nutch map reduce job getting stuck at 67%

Tags: web-crawler, nutch, solrcloud

I am using Nutch 1.17 to crawl websites and index data in Solr on my local machine. Initially, I have set parameters as topN=2, depth=2, and crawling was successful. Then, I changed the parameters as topN=3, depth=3, but the reduce process in map-reduce is stuck at 67%. This all was running with 4GB RAM.

Then, I tried with the RAM as 8GB, but the same issue persists. What can be the issue? How can I triage further? Please assist.

Below are the logs:

> 2021-04-30 17:58:58,432 INFO  mapreduce.Job - The url to track the
> job: http://localhost:8080/ 2021-04-30 17:58:58,432 INFO
> mapreduce.Job - Running job: job_local71316116_0001 2021-04-30
> 17:58:58,643 INFO  regex.RegexURLNormalizer - can't find rules for
> scope 'indexer', using default 2021-04-30 17:58:58,752 INFO
> regex.RegexURLNormalizer - can't find rules for scope 'indexer', using
> default 2021-04-30 17:58:58,840 INFO  regex.RegexURLNormalizer - can't
> find rules for scope 'indexer', using default 2021-04-30 17:58:58,890
> INFO  regex.RegexURLNormalizer - can't find rules for scope 'indexer',
> using default 2021-04-30 17:58:58,929 INFO  regex.RegexURLNormalizer -
> can't find rules for scope 'indexer', using default 2021-04-30
> 17:58:58,979 WARN  impl.MetricsSystemImpl - JobTracker metrics system
> already initialized! 2021-04-30 17:58:59,020 INFO
> indexer.IndexWriters - Index writer
> org.apache.nutch.indexwriter.solr.SolrIndexWriter identified.
> 2021-04-30 17:58:59,057 WARN  exchange.Exchanges - No exchange was
> configured. The documents will be routed to all index writers.
> 2021-04-30 17:58:59,435 INFO  mapreduce.Job - Job
> job_local71316116_0001 running in uber mode : false 2021-04-30
> 17:58:59,437 INFO  mapreduce.Job -  map 100% reduce 0% 2021-04-30
> 17:59:11,444 INFO  mapreduce.Job -  map 100% reduce 67%

Answer (score 0):

The indexer job starts sending the documents to Solr in the last third of the reduce phase. Depending on whether large documents and fields are indexed this phase might to be slower than the preceding phases of the indexer job. To look for potential reasons:

- verify that Solr is up and not reporting errors
- use the utility "jstack" to get the exact the indexer job is hanging
- topN=3 - this means you're only crawling and indexing 3 pages per cycle. This makes the problem easily reproducible: you can use the tool `bin/nutch indexchecker` to send fetch and index each of this 3 URLs individually. The URLs are logged when they are fetched.
- also look into the hadoop.log which is more verbose and includes more information than is written to stdout

Comment: 1) The solr is up and running properly. 
2) I will check with jstack.
3) Will try this.
4) I do not see an error in the hadoop.log. Is there anything specific that I can check in log, please let me know.